# Absoluteness of definability (2)

Tags: set-theory

Let $M,N$ be transitive models of set theory and $M \subset N$. Assume that in $M$ we prove that there exists an object $X$ that satisfies some set $T$ of first order properties and which is definable from ordinals. 
(here $T$ means a set of first order formulas with one free variable X in the language of set theory).

Does the same conclusion hold in $N$, i.e. does there exist an $Y$ in $N$ satisfying the same properties $T$?

Edit: by a proof in M I mean just a fact that is proven about M.

Comment: Could you be more precise? The answer depends on the details of what you mean. Do you mean the object is a structure that satisfies the theory $T$? Or do you mean that the object satisfies in $M$ all the formulas that are in $T$? That is, where $T$ is actually a $1$-type.

Comment: Also, when you say "in $M$ we prove..." do you mean just that we prove that statement *about* $M$, or do you really mean that the proof is a (possibly nonstandard) object inside $M$?

Comment: You might want to require that $M$ and $N$ have the same ordinals (and maybe even that $N$ thinks that $M$ is transitive).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Let $T$ contain just the single formula "the continuum hypothesis holds, and $x=\emptyset$". Suppose that $M\models\text{CH}$ but $N$ does not. In this case, the empty set in $M$ will satisfy every assertion in $T$, and the empty set is ordinal definable, but no object in $N$ will satisfy $T$.

Comment: I was going for $V=L$, but $\sf CH$ works too!

Comment: But I seem to think that we've already had this question recently...

Comment: No offense intended, but the answer is so trivial that I suspect the OP had something different in mind.  Just knowing that the first order theory in the language of set theory is not absolute between transitive models of ZFC is enough.